# Void wrapped function in journalctl source

Tags: c, call, void

I was recently browsing through the source code of journalctl and found a piece of code that was not really clear to me.

The part I am talking about is right here:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/9e83569d8ff219730912ecac441843b9531b079c/src/shared/logs-show.c#L1056

Seems like they want to avaoid multiple checks like this

```
r = sd_journal_add_match(...);
if (r < 0) {
    //some error
}
```

by || the outputs together.

Wouldn't that also be possible by doing something like this:

```
r = sd_journal_add_match(...);
r |= sd_journal_add_match(...);
...
```

Why wrap the output in

```
(void) ( ... );
```

?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Not sure, because I've never used such constructs, but I think it instructs the compiler to execute the calls with assignment sequentially and stop at first one which give a `result != 0`. The `(void)(....)` tells to the compiler also that the resullt of logical `||` is useless (because it's used to stop execution to the first true result). If so this is absolutely wrong and to be discouraged also because no sequence order can be defined with actual C standards where optimization can  change the order of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

```
r |= sd_journal_add_match(...);
```

is not the same as

```
(r = sd_journal_add_match(j, "_UID=0", 0)) ||
(r = sd_journal_add_match(j, m2, 0)) ||
```

The `|=` operator is a *bit-wise or* operator together with assignment (same as `r = r | sd_()`), where `||` is the *logical or* operator. All `sd_jourcal_` function are executed until one of them returns a non-zero value. Then `r` contains these non-zero value. This is called `short-circuit`evaluation.

Second, I guess it is the same reason why we (should) cast the return value of a function to `void` if you are not interested in to use them. For example:

```
(void)printf("Hello World");
```

This communicates that you now that `printf()` returns a value, but you are not check them. Usually you should check always the return value:

```
if (printf("Hello World") < 0) {
    // do some error handling here
}
```

Simply writing

```
printf("Hello World");
```

ignores the return value silently, which is a bad idea. I guess, there are tools out there (like lint) for critical software, which can check this.

For the example you provided, the result of the `||` chain is casted to `void`. Without the cast, the code looks strange, because there is a value calculated, but not assigned. Similar like this

```
f() || g(); // better (void)(f() || g());
```